# last command does not show logins with public key. Is it normal?

Tags: linux, ssh

I just finished to set up 2 Debian servers to make backups using rsync and public key authentication.
Everything works fine but... For some reason `last` command on the source server does not show any logins with public key. Is it normal? What do I need to change so that last command shows all logins?

Comment: how are you running the rsync on the source server ?

Comment: I run rsync command on the backup server. It downloads files from source server. However, last command on the source server doesn't show logins with public key. At the same time I get emails from LFD with notifications about successful login.

Comment: It's not a login, it's a remote command execution (a login is an interactive session as far as last is concerned). You can check for your rsyncs in /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log (depending on distribution).

Comment: wurtel, why you did not post as an answer? Now I understand. Just a login with public kay appears in "last" but login with sync command not.